# If $ab+bc+ca=1,$ prove that $\frac{\sqrt{5a+4}}{a+bc}+\frac{\sqrt{5b+4}}{b+ca}+\frac{\sqrt{5c+4}}{c+ab}\ge 8.$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> **Problem.** Let $a,b,c$ be non-negative real numbers satisfying $ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove that
> $$\frac{\sqrt{5a+4}}{a+bc}+\frac{\sqrt{5b+4}}{b+ca}+\frac{\sqrt{5c+4}}{c+ab}\ge 8.$$

---

I've tried to use Holder inequality without success.

$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{5a+4}}{a+bc}\right)^2.\sum_{cyc}(5a+4)^2(a+bc)^2\ge [5a+5b+5c+12]^3. \tag{1}$$

$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{5a+4}}{a+bc}\right)^2.\sum_{cyc}(5a+4)^2(a+bc)^2(b+c)^3\ge \left(\sum_{cyc}(5a+4)(b+c)\right)^3.\tag{2} $$

Which are both leads to wrong inequalities in general.

Also, a big trouble here is equality case. It is $(a,b,c)=(0,1,1)$ but when I denote $a=b\rightarrow 0$, the RHS is approximate to $8.$

> I'd like to ask two questions.

1. **Is there a better Holder using ?**

I think the appropriate one might be ugly but if you find it, please feel free to share it here.

2. **Are there others idea which are smooth enough?**

For example, Mixing variables, AM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz...etc.

I aslo hope to see a good lower bound of $\frac{\sqrt{5a+4}}{a+bc},$ which eliminates the radical form (may be the rest is simpler by $uvw$)

All ideas and comments are welcomed. Thank you for your interest!

*Remark.* About $uvw$, see [here.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791)

Comment: Have you tried the method of Lagrange Multipliers or is it not applicable?

Comment: It seems hard to apply

Comment: Try homogenation with $ab+bc+ca = 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sketch of a proof.*

By AM-GM, we have
$$\frac{\sqrt{5a+4}}{a+bc}
= \frac{2(5a+4)}{(a+bc)\cdot 2\sqrt{5a + 4}} \ge \frac{2(5a+4)}{(a+bc)\cdot \left(\frac{5a + 4}{a + 2} + a + 2\right)}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{2(5a+4)}{(a+bc)\cdot \left(\frac{5a + 4}{a + 2} + a + 2\right)} \ge 8. \tag{1}$$

We use the pqr method. Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca = 1, r = abc$. Using $p^2 \ge 3q = 3$, we have $p \ge \sqrt 3$.

(1) is written as
\begin{align*}
 f(r) &:= -8\,{r}^{4}+ \left( -8\,{p}^{2}-494\,p-4384 \right) {r}^{3}\\
 &\qquad + \left( -
 520\,{p}^{3}-3122\,{p}^{2}+2408\,p-8026 \right) {r}^{2}\\
 &\qquad + \left( -512\,
 {p}^{4}-3680\,{p}^{3}+2412\,{p}^{2}+17786\,p+1508 \right) r\\
 &\qquad +128\,{p}^{
  3}+992\,{p}^{2}-512\,p-3968\\
 &\ge 0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

We have $f''(r) = -96\,{r}^{2}+6\, \left( -8\,{p}^{2}-494\,p-4384 \right) r-1040\,{p}^{3
}-6244\,{p}^{2}+4816\,p-16052
< 0$. Thus, $f(r)$ is concave.

By degree three Schur inequality, we have $r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9} = \frac{p(2 - p)(2 + p)}{9}$. Thus, we have
$$r \ge \max\left(0, \, \frac{p(2 - p)(2 + p)}{9}\right) =: r_1.$$

Also, from $0 \le (a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 = -4\,{p}^{3}r+{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+18\,pqr-4\,{q}^{3}-27\,{r}^{2}$, we have
$$r \le - \frac{2}{27} p^3 + \frac{p}{3}
+ \frac{2}{27}(p^2 - 3)\sqrt{p^2 - 3} =: r_2.$$

We can prove that $f(r_1) \ge 0$ and $f(r_2) \ge 0$. Thus, we have $f(r) \ge 0$ on $[r_1, r_2]$. The desired result follows.

Comment: Very nice, thank you!

Comment: @TATAbox It works for your another problem. I just posted an answer for that.

Comment: I like it! It is also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740147/prove-frac1-sqrt5a4-frac1-sqrt5b4-frac1-sqrt5c4-geq1-f?rq=1

Comment: @TATAbox oh, yes.

Comment: Did you try Holder ?

Comment: @TATAbox No. I just found this easily. So I stop.

Comment: @RiverLi what is $pqr$

Comment: @Krave37 The pqr method uses the substitution $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$ to express the desired inequality in terms of $p, q, r$. Then use the relation among $p, q, r$ to prove the inequality. The relation among $p, q, r$ includes the well-known inequalities e.g. $p^2 \ge 3q$ (that is $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge ab + bc + ca$), $q^2 \ge 3pr$ etc. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525858/proving-frac1ab-frac1bc-frac1ca-frac2a2b2c2-ge-fra/4526282#4526282

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks for such an awesome method, but can you elaborate exactly how will we go forward from here

Comment: @Krave37 I added the pqr proof. It is not nice here.

Comment: @River Li I checked your proof. Indeed, $f''(w^3)<0$. Beautiful solution! $b=a$ and $c=\frac{1-a^2}{2a}$ give $a(1-a)(4a^7-34a^6-497a^5+38a^4+782a^3+222a^2-77a+8)\geq0,$ which is true for $0<a\leq1.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks for checking. uvw is more terse.