# Minimizing $ \sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{5a+8bc}}{8a+5bc}$ with $ \sum\limits_{cyc}ab=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials

**Olympiad inequality.** Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=1.$ Find the minimal value $P$ of $$f:=\frac{\sqrt{5a+8bc}}{8a+5bc}+\frac{\sqrt{5b+8ca}}{8b+5ca}+\frac{\sqrt{5c+8ab}}{8c+5ab}.$$
*Note:* Often Stack Exchange asks to show some work before answering the question. This inequality was used as a proposed problem for the National TST of an Asian country a few years back. However, upon receiving the official solution, the committee decided to drop this problem immediately. They didn't believe that any student can solve this problem in the $3$ hour timeframe.

It seems that minimum is achieved at $(a,b,c)=(0,1,1).$ I've tried to prove
$$f\ge \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}+\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{5}. \tag{1}$$
A big problem around here is $a=b=c=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ since $LHS_{(1)}-RHS_{(1)}\approx 0.000151$

I hope to see some ideas. Thank you!

**Update 1:** There are two answers and RiverLi's proof is good but not easy to full it by hand.

**Update 2:** You can see also [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458693/maximizing-p-frac-sqrt5a8bc8a5bc-frac-sqrt5b8ca8b5ca-frac-s)

Comment: Maybe the substitution $x=\sqrt{bc}$, $y=\sqrt{ac}$, and $z=\sqrt{ab}$ can help.,

Comment: It's really hard to find an elegant solution.

Comment: @TATAbox I failed to find a better solution. Perhaps the author of the problem uses some tricky ways which are not easy for others.

Comment: WA says the it is minimum when $a=b=c=\frac{\sqrt3}{3}$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimize+%24%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B5%7Cx%7C%2B8%7Cyz%7C%7D%7D%7B8%7Cx%7C%2B5%7Cyz%7C%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B5%7Cy%7C%2B8%7Cxz%7C%7D%7D%7B8%7Cy%7C%2B5%7Cxz%7C%7D+%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B5%7Cz%7C%2B8%7Cyx%7C%7D%7D%7B8%7Cz%7C%2B5%7Cyx%7C%7D%24+such+that+%7Cxy%7C%2B%7Cyz%7C%2B%7Czx%7C%3D1

Comment: @pie You can check it again.

Comment: @RiverLi We're waiting for official solution.

Comment: where did you get this question from ?

Comment: @pie It's from India TST.

Comment: @pie So wolfram alpha (WA) fails to find the global minimum or incorrect input in WA?

Comment: @RiverLi I am not very good at writing in wolfram alpha maybe I did something wrong but I don't see anything wrong with the input

Comment: @pie WA trapped me sometimes.

Comment: since 5 days has passed since you started the bounty and there still no answer maybe after the bounty post this again in math overflow

Comment: What is math overflow?

Comment: math overflow https://mathoverflow.net/ is the same as MSE the only difference is that math overfolw is a place for advanced and hard question in the graduate level so there are many mathematicians there like terry tao for example

Comment: I think this question will do well in math overflow try to post it there and put a link to this question and refer that you asked this question here and even after the bounty you didn't get any answers that the author of the question thought of

Comment: Thank you @pie. I'll do it later.

Comment: tell me when you do because I want to see an answer to this question

Comment: Very hard problem. Some Indian proposers called this problem is a monster. Is an original solution available ?

Comment: I am still waiting a nice proof.

Comment: @TATAbox me too

Comment: 99% is impossible.

Comment: Still no answer :(

Comment: @pie It is extremally hard, hmm

Answer (score 6):

**Some thoughts.**

Let
$$x := 5a + 8bc, \quad y := 5b + 8ca, \quad z := 5c + 8ab,$$
$$u := 8a + 5bc, \quad v := 8b + 5ca, \quad w := 8c + 5ab.$$
Let
$$A := \frac{2\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{5}}{3}, \quad B := \frac{8\sqrt{5} - 10\sqrt{2}}{3}.$$

By AM-GM, we have
$$
 \frac{\sqrt{5a+8bc}}{8a+5bc}
 = \frac{x}{u}\cdot \frac{2}{2\sqrt{x}}
 \ge \frac{x}{u} \cdot \frac{2}{\frac{x}{Ax + B} + (Ax + B)} = \frac{2x(Ax + B)}{ux + u(Ax + B)^2}.
$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{2x(Ax + B)}{ux + u(Ax + B)^2}
+ \frac{2y(Ay + B)}{vy + v(Ay + B)^2} + \frac{2z(Az + B)}{wz + w(Az + B)^2}
\ge \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}+\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{5}. \tag{1}$$

We use the pqr method.
Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca = 1, r = abc$. We have
$$p^2 \ge 3q, \quad q^2 \ge 3pr, \quad r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}. \tag{2}$$
(*Note*: $r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}$ is the degree three Schur inequality.)

(1) is equivalently written as
$$C(p, r) \sqrt{5} + D(p, r)\sqrt{2} \ge 0 \tag{3}$$
where $C(p, r)$ and $D(p, r)$ are two polynomials. <sup>1)</sup>

(3) is true for all $p, r \ge 0$ with $1 \ge 3pr$
and $p^2 \ge 3$ and $r \ge \frac{4p - p^3}{9}$, which is verified
by *Mathematica* - a Computer Algebra System (CAS).
Thus, (1) is true. We need to find a proof of (3) which can be verified easily.

---

**Footnotes.**

<sup>1)</sup>

\begin{align*}
 C &:= -307200000\,{p}^{6}{r}^{3}-313344000\,{p}^{5}{r}^{3}-1175040000\,{p}^{
  4}{r}^{4}\\
 &\qquad -3138240000\,{p}^{5}{r}^{2}+10636876800\,{p}^{4}{r}^{3}+
 560793600\,{p}^{3}{r}^{4}\\
 &\qquad -1400832000\,{p}^{2}{r}^{5}+3206832000\,{p}^{
  4}{r}^{2}-30808175040\,{p}^{3}{r}^{3}\\
 &\qquad +15838519680\,{p}^{2}{r}^{4}+
 1699430400\,p{r}^{5}-491520000\,{r}^{6}\\
 &\qquad +2202240000\,{p}^{4}r+
 92830480200\,{p}^{3}{r}^{2}-282601800\,{p}^{2}{r}^{3}\\
 &\qquad -29734119264\,p{r
 }^{4}+1220244480\,{r}^{5}+10496784000\,{p}^{3}r\\
&\qquad -195792425400\,{p}^{2}{
  r}^{2}+171792599925\,p{r}^{3}-1397911875\,{r}^{4}\\
 &\qquad -33643248000\,{p}^{2}
 r-32289450120\,p{r}^{2}-179729064750\,{r}^{3}\\
 &\qquad +768000000\,{p}^{2}+
 40110748800\,pr+173550992400\,{r}^{2}\\
 &\qquad +4915200000\,p-31985030400\,r-
 12902400000
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 D &:= -491520000\,{p}^{6}{r}^{3}-319488000\,{p}^{5}{r}^{3}-1880064000\,{p}^{
  4}{r}^{4}\\
 &\qquad -5061120000\,{p}^{5}{r}^{2}+15576883200\,{p}^{4}{r}^{3}+
 1421721600\,{p}^{3}{r}^{4}\\
 &\qquad -2241331200\,{p}^{2}{r}^{5}+6120960000\,{p}^
 {4}{r}^{2}-46081374720\,{p}^{3}{r}^{3}\\
 &\qquad +22093286400\,{p}^{2}{r}^{4}+
 3092643840\,p{r}^{5}-786432000\,{r}^{6}\\
 &\qquad +3494400000\,{p}^{4}r+
 143923780800\,{p}^{3}{r}^{2}+694726080\,{p}^{2}{r}^{3}\\
 &\qquad -43404609792\,p{
  r}^{4}+331849728\,{r}^{5}+16226880000\,{p}^{3}r\\
 &\qquad -307929041040\,{p}^{2}{
  r}^{2}+266002645320\,p{r}^{3}+157445640\,{r}^{4}\\
 &\qquad -51839472000\,{p}^{2}r
 -50083230240\,p{r}^{2}-284401827024\,{r}^{3}\\
 &\qquad +1248000000\,{p}^{2}+
 62068857600\,pr+275071716480\,{r}^{2}\\
 &\qquad +7641600000\,p-50523340800\,r-
 20275200000.
\end{align*}

Comment: It's impressive! How did you find the first AM_GM estimate?

Comment: @Dragonboy Recently, we dealt with some problems in MSE using the estimate of the form $\frac{2}{2\sqrt{x}}\ge \frac{2}{\frac{x}{A} + A}$ for some undetermined function $A$. For example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4790340/if-abbcca-1-prove-that-frac-sqrt5a4abc-frac-sqrt5b4bca). Here I tried $A = p_1 (5a + 8bc) + p_2$ from $\frac{2}{\sqrt{5a + 8bc}}$.

Comment: It is interesting, indeed.

Comment: My congrats, you're awarded 100+. I also accepted it.

Comment: @Dragonboy Thanks. It is a nice and difficult problem.

Comment: @RiverLi A long time ago, I saw a problem: 
Given $a,b,c$ be non-negative real numbers such that $ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove that$$\frac{\sqrt{a+bc}}{a+5}+\frac{\sqrt{b+ca}}{b+5}+\frac{\sqrt{c+ab}}{c+5}\le \frac{8}{15}.$$
I think your approach works for it.

Comment: @TATAbox Interesting.

Answer (score 3):

**Not an solution, just some thoughts**

Let $f(a,b,c)$ be the expression we want to minimize. Suppose one of the variables is $0$, and the other two are inverses of each other. WLOG, assume $a=0, b=\frac{1}{c}$. We get:

$f(0,\frac{1}{c},c) = \frac{\sqrt{8}}{5} + \frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{c}}}{\frac{8}{c}} + \frac{\sqrt{5c}}{8c} = \frac{\sqrt{8}}{5} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}\left(\sqrt{c} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}\right)$

By AM-GM, it's now clear $f(0,\frac{1}{c},c) \geq \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{5} +  \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$.

From this point on, assume, WLOG, $a\geq b\geq c>0$.

Claim 1: $\min(a,b,c) \leq 1$.

Proof: Suppose not. Then $ac+ab+bc=1$ is impossible. $\blacksquare$

Claim 2: If $a\geq b\geq c$, then $1 \geq  b\geq c$.

Proof: Suppose not. Then $a\geq b > 1$. Meaning $ab>1$. Meaning $ab+bc+ac=1$ is impossible. $\blacksquare$

Claim 3: $abc \leq \frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$.

Proof: AM-GM gives $\frac{ab+bc+ac}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}} \implies \frac{1}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}} \implies \frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}} \geq abc$ $\blacksquare$

Claim 4: $a+b+c \geq \sqrt[3]{3\sqrt{3}}$

Proof: Direct application of claim 3 and AM-GM $\blacksquare$

Claim 5: $a+b+c \geq \sqrt{3}$

Let $S=a+b+c$ and $P = abc$. We can say that $a,b,c$ are the roots of an polynomial $g(x) = x^{3} - Sx^{2} + x - P$. For $g$ to have 3 real roots, we must have that $g$ has an critical point above $0$, and another below $0$. Meaning

$3x^{2} -2Sx + 1 = 0 \implies x = \frac{2S\pm2\sqrt{S^{2} - 3}}{2} = S \pm \sqrt{S^{2}-3}$

Must have real roots, so $S \geq \sqrt{3}$.$\blacksquare$

Claim 6: If $b=c$, then $a\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, and $b=c=\sqrt{a^{2}-1}-a$

Suppose we know that two of the variables are equal. Then, either $a=b=1$ (which we already solved), or $1 \geq b=c$. In this situation we have that $ac + ab + bc = 1 \implies b(b+2a)=1 \implies b^{2}+2ab - 1=0 \implies b=\frac{-2a\pm 2\sqrt{a^{2}+1}}{2} = \sqrt{a^{2}+1}-a$ (since $b>0$).

Enforcing $a\geq b$, we get that this has an solution whenever $a\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. $\blacksquare$

So, if we plug in $f(a,\sqrt{a^{2}+1}-a,\sqrt{a^{2}+1}-a)$, $a\geq \frac1{\sqrt{3}}$, we fairly easily check $f(a,\sqrt{a^{2}+1}-a,\sqrt{a^{2}+1}-a) > f(1,1,0)$

Meaning if there is an minimum, and it is not $f(1,1,0)$, it must occur with $a\neq b\neq c$. So it suffices to show this is not possible.

From this point on, we suppose $a>b>c$. We also know $1\geq b > c$.

I ran out of ideas here. I suspect one can prove that $f(a,b,c) \geq f(a,\sqrt{a^{2}+1}-a,\sqrt{a^{2}+1}-a)$ whenever $a\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, which would be enough, but I have been unable to do so.

Comment: I tried to continue but it's hard for me

Comment: @Dragonboy for me as well. Im not even sure im on the right path. This was just my attempt.

Comment: I upvoted for your try. Hope you can full it in near future.